# SQL, Stock movements where no zero stock records

Tags: sql

I'm trying to create a stock movement file from historical stock records, see picture:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tDJI2.png]

I've been able to get the green movements and the orange value (had some luck union all to a 0 stock record for `max(day) + 1` and removing anything less than today).  Movements are then generated with a lag function.

The difficulty is there are no 0 stock records.  i.e. fifth row in the example above there is no record so unable to create the correct movement to 0 with the -2.  It would create movements of -10, -4, -4, 5, -3, -1, -3

Is there any easier way to identify the gaps and create phantom 0's,  I know the dates (these are a mix of weekly that will become daily)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to get the missing gaps in this case it looks like you have a date every week (or 7 days) and in some case there is no date.  So you can build a date table with a while loop and do a join and assinging Stock Opening Balance as 0 when null in your table.  Here is something similar I am using table variables to simply but using a temp table would probably be better for you and if you do you don't need 2 tables just insert the missing to your temp table.

```
DECLARE @TableWithGaps AS TABLE ([Date] DATE, StockOpeningBalance INT)
INSERT INTO @TableWithGaps ([Date],StockOpeningBalance)
    VALUES ('2016-04-04',10)
,('2016-04-11',6)
,('2016-04-18',2)
,('2016-05-09',7)
,('2016-05-16',4)
,('2016-05-23',3)

DECLARE @Dates AS TABLE ([Date] DATE)

DECLARE @MinDate DATE =  '3/28/2016'
DECLARE @MaxDate DATE =  '6/20/2016'

--Could also get first record as minimum date and last record, or set @maxdate = GETDATE()
--SELECT @MinDate = DATEADD(DAY,7,MIN([Date])), @MaxDate = MAX([Date]) FROM @TableWithGaps

WHILE @MinDate < DATEADD(DAY,1,@MaxDate)
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO @Dates ([Date]) VALUES (@MinDate)

    SET @MinDate = DATEADD(DAY,7,@MinDate)
END

SELECT
    d.[Date]
    ,StockOpeningBalance = ISNULL(StockOpeningBalance,0)
    ,LAG(ISNULL(StockOpeningBalance,0),1,0) OVER (ORDER BY d.[Date])
    ,Movements = ISNULL(StockOpeningBalance,0) - LAG(ISNULL(StockOpeningBalance,0),1,0) OVER (ORDER BY d.[Date])
FROM
    @Dates d
    LEFT JOIN @TableWithGaps s
    ON d.[Date] = s.[Date]
```

Also note, I prefer temp tables over table variables and they temp tables will perform better with a larger data set.  If you start doing a ton with dates you may want to look at a date dimension table for purposes like this. If you are using Microsoft SSAS it has a built in tool to generate one that you can google/search for pretty quickly.

Comment: Hi Matt Thanks for getting back to me - I will try to implement what you have suggested and let you know how I get on!

Comment: Hope it helps.  I did just change it around slightly it will be better performance if you have a large data set/date range.

Comment: @Rob_Heat if my answer got you to the solution could you please accept it.  I am doing this to help the community but also wanting to build the reputation up as well.  thanks!. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: Hi Matt, apologies for not pinging it.  Your query above definitely helped me get the end result needed.  It is very much appreciated